# How to handle tiny blinds where everybody bets

Tags: tournament, blinds

In a private online tournament with friends we have 20k chip buy in but the blinds start about 20. So in much of the early game everyone pretty much just bets.

How can I bully people off the pot and assert some dominance?

Answer (score 1):

Wow, 1000bb deep, you will not see that every day :) if you want to put more pressure on your opponents the best way to do it is by using proper bet sizing.

You can raise bigger preflop to lower stack to pot ratio and then use some overbets. In these situations, players do not want to risk too much without premium hands or even nuts so you will get more folds than normally in such spot.

But again, when you play home games with friends, a sound strategy sometimes does not work too well, right? :D

Comment: Can you expand with _how_ big it would make sense - I am used to betting based on blinds/pot but in terms of stack some examples would be helpful.

Comment: There is no fixed answer to this one since you have to test it and see how specific players react. I have played in the games where opening 15bb preflop is normal and everyone seems to keep calling, so see what sizing you can get away with and then go for it.

Answer (score 0):

My advice would be to play good, solid poker, paying special atention to profitable speculative situations (you may want to call some bets more loosely because of implicit odds)

Answer (score 0):

Depends whether you want to play poker or gamble. Games like these are where sharks love to swim. Play very tight, top 15% hands. Pay attention to the range of your opponets, build the image. Mid-game keep up the image, dont try to bluff low stakes, amateus dont care. When playing play agressive, and from the position. A lot of times you can call all ins when seeing flush draws etc as flushing is common, and 4 to 1 odds are good. Build stack, win.